# Formatting issue with Zend textarea

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-view

I have a text area which I use to entered the following text with those line breaks, so it looks like paragraphs already. I save it into the database, and I can see the format is still being preserved.

> This is some text.
>
> And this another line. And this
>   another line. And this another line.
>   And this another line. And this
>   another line. And this another line.
>   And this another line. And this
>   another line. And this another line.
>   And this another line.
>
> And this another line. And this
>   another line. And this another line.
>   And this another line. And this
>   another line.

But when I pull the data from the database and display it, it looks all like 1 line.

> This is some text. And this another
>   line. And this another line. And this
>   another line. And this another line.
>   And this another line. And this
>   another line. And this another line.
>   And this another line. And this
>   another line. And this another line.
>   And this another line. And this
>   another line. And this another line.
>   And this another line. And this
>   another line. Clip 1 by user 1 And
>   this another line. And this another
>   line. And this another line. And this
>   another line. And this another line.
>   And this another line. And this
>   another line. And this another line.
>   And this another line. And this
>   another line. And this another line.
>   And this another line. And this
>   another line. And this another line.
>   And this another line.

but when I view the HTML source, I see it's separated into 3 lines.

What should I do to make it display in 3 paragraphs?

Comment: It`s a not zend-related, but mostly HTML-related. You could chahge tags here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you display the text you may have to wrap it in a call to [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php):

```
echo nl2br($test);
```

Comment: Something to keep in mind about nl2br is that it retains the newline in its return value.  (e.g. "test\n" will return "test<br>\n".) This means that running nl2br(nl2br("test\n")) will actually <br> twice.